# Spring Data audit annotations @creationDate & @LastModifiedDate isn't working with sub document of mongo @EnableMongoAuditing

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-annotations

Spring audit annotation working on Top level (processStatus) document but not for sub document (stepsDetails).

```
    @Document(collection = "processStatus")
    public class ProcessStatus {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;        

    @Field("steps")
    private Collection<StepDetails> steps;
    @Version
    private Long version;

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;   

    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastModifiedDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String lastModifiedBy;
    ... //not including getter/setters

}
```

Sub-Document

```
   @Document(collection="stepsDetails")
   public class StepDetails{
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    @Field("name")
    private String step;
    @Field("status")
    private String status;  

    @Version
    private Long version;   

    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastModifiedDate;  

}
```

I added @EnableMongoAuditing on the configuration class. When I insert the processStatus document in the mongo db, i found that audit fields in the StepDetails are not populated. I need to have this working because various processes update the stepDetails multiple times.

These annotations are supported in sub document?? anyone knows how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Also ran into this same issue. You can have your domain objects implement the Auditable interface and its methods. You can also use a RepositoryEventHandler to set the sub document's fields manually.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.10.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#auditing